# Smallest number in an unordered array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to find the smallest number in an array for my homework and I have looked at a lot of examples but it still doesnt solve my problem.
I am supposed to use

```
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 28.1, 60.8];
console.log(smallestNumber(values)); // expect 28.1
```

to test my code. This is what I have right now. I tested it and my result is NaN

```
let smallestNumber = function() {
  return Math.min(values)
};
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 28.1, 60.8];
console.log(smallestNumber(values));//expect 28.1
```

Comment: "I am supposed to" -- this sounds like homework. Are you asking for help on your assignment? `values` is not defined in your function.

Comment: Yessir, I think you are supposed to not use `Math.min`, instead, you should write the code that should go into the implementation of `Math.min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math.min expects arguments and not an array, so using destructure ES6 feature we do just that

```js
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 28.1, 60.8];
let smallestNumber = args => Math.min(...args)
console.log(smallestNumber(values));//expect 28.1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn to program and not just use existing programs, You should learn and write something like this.

```js
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 28.1, 60.8];
let smallestNumber = function(values) {
  smallest = values[0];
  for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    if(values[i] < smallest)
    {
      smallest = values[i];
    }
  }
  return smallest;
};
console.log(smallestNumber(values));//expect 28.1
```

Comment: "smallest = 0;", what if there were negative numbers?! you should change it to `smallest = -Infinity`" or simply to `smallest = values[0]`